# How to select rows based on the Max Value grouping by a column in R?

Tags: r, max

I have the following table:

```
df<-cbind(c(35780,35780,35780,35800,35800,35800,35800,35830,35830,35830,35830),c("Semi_urban","Rural","Urban","Multiurban","Semi_urban","Rural","Urban","Multiurban","Semi_urban","Rural","Urban"),c(0,0,2,0,0,0,11,1,1,0,0))

df

colnames(df)<-c("Zip_Code","Zone_type","Freq")
```

I want to extract the raws with Maximum for each Zip Code, if the Maximum is repeated I want to extract both lines:

```
df.final<-cbind(c(35780,35800,35830,35830),c("Urban","Urban","Multiurban","Semi-urban"),c(2,11,1,1))
df.final
```

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: @Felip Are you sure you want a matrix as output? It can only contain elements of 1 type, characters in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you need matrix output. Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df %>% as.tibble() %>% type.convert(as.is = T) %>% group_by(Zip_Code) %>% slice_max(Freq) %>% as.matrix()
     Zip_Code Zone_type    Freq
[1,] "35780"  "Urban"      " 2"
[2,] "35800"  "Urban"      "11"
[3,] "35830"  "Multiurban" " 1"
[4,] "35830"  "Semi_urban" " 1"
```

Comment: `Freq` is of a character type. You should use `slice_max(as.numeric(Freq))`.

Comment: @ekoam, thanks, have used type.convert, as I usually use that.

Answer (score 1):

The `data.table` equivalent:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[,.SD[Freq == max(Freq)],by = Zip_Code]

   Zip_Code  Zone_type Freq
1:    35780      Urban    2
2:    35800      Urban   11
3:    35830 Multiurban    1
4:    35830 Semi_urban    1
```

In Karthik's answer you can also do  `filter(Freq == max(Freq))` instead of `slice_max(Freq)`, which is more intuitive I think.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solutions of the other users, there is also one that only uses base `R`.

```r
df <- cbind(c(35780,35780,35780,35800,35800,35800,35800,35830,35830,35830,35830),
            c("Semi_urban","Rural","Urban","Multiurban","Semi_urban","Rural","Urban","Multiurban","Semi_urban","Rural","Urban"),
            c(0,0,2,0,0,0,11,1,1,0,0))

df <- as.data.frame(df)

colnames(df) <- c("Zip_Code","Zone_type","Freq")

df$Zip_Code <- as.character(df$Zip_Code)
df$Freq <- as.integer(as.character(df$Freq))
df$Zone_type <- as.character(df$Zone_type)


ls.result <- lapply(split(df, f = df$Zip_Code),
                    function(df.for.zip.code)
                    {
                        subset(df.for.zip.code,
                        subset = Freq == max(Freq))
                    })

df.result <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), ls.result)
df.result
```